# Using AWS DMS for EC2 MariaDB instance to MariaDB RDS instance

Tags: mariadb, aws, amazon-ec2

After combing through AWS documentation, I am still unclear if DMS supports migration from EC2 instances running latest mariadb version to RDS mariadb instance?I see that MySQL is supported, but am I making the wrong assumption that mariadb is not?

I attempted to setup a migration project, using two end points and data sources as suggested by AWS, but when I try to select the source data source, nothing is present...and then if I select the target endpoint/data source, it claims the engine is not supported. Which...doesn't make sense why it would even allow me to select a data source as mariadb.

Due to the size of my database, which will become an archive in RDS, the only approach that seemed less hands on was DMS. However, it seems I will need to create a full backup (which usually takes almost up to 48 hours, pulling one of the primary nodes out of replication and load balancer pool) in order to do it. If that is my only option, so be it. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a break and came back to looking at DMS to find out that I either was setting up the migration task incorrectly, or there was an update to the DMS service since I last looked at it. Regardless, it is possible to migrate from a self-managed MariaDB instance using TokuDB storage engine, running on an EC2 instance, to AWS RDS. We are in the process of migrating to Aurora MySQL, and I was able to successfully use DMS to migrate with a few minor modifications. [This Amazon blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrate-self-managed-mariadb-to-amazon-aurora-mysql) describes the use of AWS DMS to do said task.

There are a few parameters you may need to change when setting up the end points, specifically the source EC2 instance in my case, so pay attention to what AWS recommends you use. These parameters are both specific to the end point, and the changes can be made directly to the `my.cnf` file (or `50-server.cnf` for newer versions of MariaDB).